# ionic routing TypeError: $state.$current.locals is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a problems , i need to create routes in ionic , so when a put my libs like that

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src="SRC/JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="SRC/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-aria.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

i have this error

> TypeError: $state.$current.locals is undefined

but when i put my angular-ui-router before ionic libs

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src="SRC/JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="SRC/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-aria.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

i have this error

> Error: transition superseded
>   Trace de la pile :
>   $get@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js:51771:42
>
> Error: transition prevented
>   Trace de la pile :
>   $get@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js:51772:41
>
> Error: transition aborted
>   Trace de la pile :
>   $get@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js:51773:39
>
> Error: transition failed
>   Trace de la pile :
>   $get@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.js:51774:38

so where i have to put my lib ??

this is my simple route

```
 routeApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                templateUrl: 'Template/side-menu-template.html',
                abstract: true
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');


    });
```

html

```
<ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
```

if someone can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I could not figure out the proper fix (seems to do something with library versions incompatibility).

As a workaround I have replaced

```
<ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
```

with

```
<div ui-view> </div>
```